# Initialize Type by name string in .net

Tags: c#

I have an application that reads its setting at startup from App.config. The application may use different presistent storage providers. Currently I have two implemented: Oracle and Dummy (for test purposes).

Now in my Program.cs I read the name of the type of storage to use. It may be either OracleStorage or DemoStorage. These are type names, the implementations of which reside in a separate dll project.

Now, how do I instantiate an object given that I have a type name?

So I could write:

```
IStorageProvider storage = new typof(myStorageClassNameReadFromAppConfig);
```

Comment: look at Castle Windor IoC (http://www.castleproject.org/container/) for the easy way ot use Activator.CreateInstance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) combined with [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

```
IStorageProvider storage = 
        (IStorageProvider) Activator.CreateInstance(
                             Type.GetType(myStorageClassNameReadFromAppConfig)
                           );
```

Comment: Hmm, I am getting a "Could not load type 'DemoTerminalStorage' from assembly 'UZTerminal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'." Exception Message. Seems like it is trying to search only in the local assembly. I have using statement in place to reference a dll namespace that my "DemoTerminalStorage" resides in though. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: @Maxim: You may need to pass in the assembly qualified type name: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx

Comment: I had to specify the assembly name like "UZ.Termanal.Core.Data.DemoTerminalStorage, UZTerminal.Core" given that I have UZTerminal.Core.dll